# Geb & Spock - If/Then/Else logic - How to check for a record and do one thing if it exists but continue on if it doesn't

Tags: testing, if-statement, logic, spock, geb

I'm testing the creation and then removal of a record on my site using Geb/Spock.  However I can't create the record if it already exists and so I check for the existence of the record and remove it if it exists in the beginning of the test.  The problem occurs when the record does not exist, causing the test to fail. Is there a way to incorporate some if/then/else logic so the test will continue if it does not find the record in the beginning and remove it if it does find it?

Edit for example code:

```java
/**
 * Integration test for Create Record
**/
class CreateAndRemoveRecordSpec extends GebSpec {

def 'check to make sure record 999 does not exist'() {

    given: 'user is at Account Page'
    to MyAccountPage

    when: 'the user clicks the sign in link'
    waitFor { header.signInLink.click() }

    and: 'user logs on with credentials'
    at LoginPage
    loginWith(TEST_USER)

    then: 'user is at landing page.'
    at MyAccountPage

    and: 'list of saved records is displayed'
    myList.displayed

    /* I would like some sort of if here so the test doesn't fail if there is no record*/
    when: 'record 999 exists'
    record(999).displayed

    then: 'remove record 999'
    deleteRecord(999).click()

    /* continue on with other tests without failing whether or not the record exists */
}

def 'test to create record 999'() {}

def 'test to remove record 999'() {}
```

Comment: Hard to say without some code to go by, but can you catch an exception if the record does not exist?

Comment: Added some Geb Spock code to give a better picture of what I'm trying to do.

Comment: What class is `record`?

Comment: Could you do something like `when: \ record(999).displayed\ then:\
def e = thrown(SomeException)`

Comment: Can you remove the record before you run the tests using sql?

Comment: No, I can only access the records via services I have no access to the data directly.  Not sure about catching exceptions like that, I'll do some research.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
when: 'record 999 exists'
def displayed = record(999).displayed

then: 'remove record 999'
!displayed || deleteRecord(999).click()
```

If record(999) isn't displayed then the `!displayed` statement will evaluate to true, and so the `deleteRecord(999).click()` shouldn't get evaluated, therefore causing the test to pass.

When the record is displayed, `!displayed` will evaluate to false, and so spock will have to evaluate the `deleteRecord(999).click()` statement, providing the desired behavior.

This works based on short-circuit evaluation (which Java and Groovy both use) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation

Comment: It's a bit of a hack, also doing `displayed && deleteRecord(999).click()` might make a little bit more sense than using the `||` but that's just preference!

Comment: I will say '&&' is more stronger :)