# Spock: if-else check in spock - Check element visibbility

Tags: if-statement, testing, groovy, spock, geb

I need to click login button if logout button is not displayed and logout button if login button is not displayed.

How I can check this in when,then blocks in Spock?

I mean how if-else is supported in Spock?

In the Page, I have the content like below:

```
logout(required: false) { $("a",text:"ログアウト") }
```

than I have to check if ログアウト which mean logout is present or not.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25368067/geb-spock-if-then-else-logic-how-to-check-for-a-record-and-do-one-thing-if) does not address my issue becasue it is checking a Boolean value which is being checked in the **last part** of the def. If I have more code to execute after this check, and if I cannot take actions if the Boolean is false in an else like block, than I cannot go ahead.

Comment: Please show your code[How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: This question does not need to show any sample code. This is a generic question whether Spock supports if-else check of element visibility and if yes than how? But just to make clearer, I will show some sample code I trying to implement.

Comment: Or... do you mean something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25368067/geb-spock-if-then-else-logic-how-to-check-for-a-record-and-do-one-thing-if

Comment: This question is not appropriate for my case. I saw this question too.

Answer (score 0):

The main concept of tests is check each functionality separately.
I can't understand from the question what is the code check.
But the recipe should be like that:

**First test**:

setup: Make all the conditions so the logout button is not displayed.
when: press the login button.
then: Check the behavior.

**Second test**:

setup: Make all the conditions so the login button is not displayed.
when: press the logout button.
then: Check the behavior.

It is better not checking 'if else' statement in the same test.

The separation enables checking each part of the 'if else' by itself.